# Meteor: Can't run a newly created app Win10 x64

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, npm-install

I am trying to learn Meteor but I can't even make the first tutorial work.

```
PS >meteor create test
PS >cd test
PS \test> npm install
up to date in 1.644s
PS \test> meteor

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

W20180527-15:47:22.220(9)? (STDERR) module.js:549
W20180527-15:47:22.261(9)? (STDERR)     throw err;
W20180527-15:47:22.262(9)? (STDERR)     ^
W20180527-15:47:22.263(9)? (STDERR)
W20180527-15:47:22.268(9)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
W20180527-15:47:22.269(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
W20180527-15:47:22.271(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
W20180527-15:47:22.272(9)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
W20180527-15:47:22.274(9)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
W20180527-15:47:22.274(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspace\meteor\test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:1:75)
W20180527-15:47:22.275(9)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
W20180527-15:47:22.276(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
W20180527-15:47:22.277(9)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
W20180527-15:47:22.278(9)? (STDERR)     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
W20180527-15:47:22.278(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

=> Exited with code: 1
```

I tried:

1. Installing the missing module manually gives another missing module but there is just too many of them missing.
2. npm install was not doing anything so I tried using npm-install-missing but it just says no missing modules.
3. Reinstalling Meteor, NodeJS and npm. No difference.

Windows 10 Pro x64
Meteor 1.6.1.1
Node v8.11.2
NPM 5.6.0

How do I run this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last Windows 10 update made Meteor dependencies stop working.
Meteor published a release specifically for this problem. You can get it by using:

```
meteor update --release 1.6.1.2-rc.0
```

[See the Github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9887#issuecomment-392285751)

[See the commit on the Meteor repository](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/cd4f8d41c9a1f671b1ef22337601f39059d76eb9)

Answer (score 0):

How about developing your Meteor app in a Linux virtual machine? Then you could follow these instructions:

1. Get VirtualBox, https://www.virtualbox.org/
2. Choose a Linux distro (Ubuntu is a good option because you’ll find lots of help examples online. Or CentOS, since it’s mentioned by Meteor)
3. Linux instructions for Meteor, https://www.meteor.com/install

Ubuntu - https://www.ubuntu.com/

CentOS - https://www.centos.org/

You could also try installing Ubuntu for Windows:
https://blog.ubuntu.com/2016/03/30/ubuntu-on-windows-the-ubuntu-userspace-for-windows-developers

I’ve developed Meteor apps successfully in an Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows.